# ERROR: [on_request_read] connection reset by peer in R shiny

Tags: r, error-handling, shiny

I get this error:

```
ERROR: [on_request_read] connection reset by peer
```

multiple times in my console in my R-Shiny app. The program works as intended, bug free. My question is, is there a function or something I can implement in order to consume this error message and stop it from appearing in my console?

Answer (score 0):

This is a common error. I believe it has to do with the version of Shiny you use as well as your default web browser. There is currently no solution for it. I do not think this issue happens if you run your app in the window view, only for viewer pane and external (again depending on web browser).

Comment: Latest shiny version and Chrome/Firefox . The window view is not option, I have the app deployed in a website.