# Shiny failed to connect to ODBC

Tags: shiny, shiny-server, shiny-reactivity

I am trying to have Shiny connects to Teradata.

Below is the code I have but I always get "ERROR: [on_request_read] connection reset by peer" after I choose the indicator and click the action button. Appreciated any input for this. Thanks.

```
                ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
              titlePanel("Generic grapher"),
              sidebarLayout(
                sidebarPanel(

                  numericInput("wafer", label = h3("Select Indicator:"),
                               value = NULL),

                  actionButton("do", "An action button")
                ),

                mainPanel(
                  verbatimTextOutput("value"),
                  verbatimTextOutput("que"),
                  verbatimTextOutput("wq_print"),
                  dataTableOutput(outputId="pos")
                )
              )
            )
            )

            library(markdown)
            library(RODBC)
            library(DBI)
            library(sqldf)
            ch<-odbcConnect("xxx", uid=" ",pwd=" ") 
            wq = data.frame()

            server <- shinyServer(function(input, output){

              values <- reactiveValues()
              values$df <- data.frame()

              d <- eventReactive(input$do, { input$wafer })

              output$value <- renderPrint({ d() }) 

              a <- reactive({ paste("SELECT * FROM dwname.tablename WHERE indicator_x = ", d(), sep="") })

              output$que <- renderPrint({ a() }) 

              observe({
                if (!is.null(d())) {
                  wq <- reactive({  sqlQuery( a() ) })

                  output$wq_print <- renderPrint({ print(str(wq())) })

                  values$df <- rbind(isolate(values$df), wq())
                }
              })

              output$pos <- renderDataTable({ values$df })  

            })

            shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Does your app work or does it crash from the error?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44721008/error-on-request-read-connection-reset-by-peer-in-r-shiny